# Is this a good hash function?

Tags: cryptography, hash

```
unsigned int hash(bytearray[] msg) { 
  unsigned int hash = 0xDECAFEBAD; 
  for(i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) { 
    hash = ((hash << 4) XOR (hash >> 28)) XOR msg[i]; 
  }
  return (hash BITWISE-AND 0x7FFFFFFF); 
}
```

Comment: What are you going to be using the hash function for? Something that requires a secure hash? Other?

Comment: hphone with really old hardware

Comment: What's an hphone? Presumably you don't mean [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc248027.aspx).

Comment: I am sorry. Ignore the h.

Comment: This doesn't look like a secure hash function so manufacturing a collision is trivial.  The rotate amount (4) is a factor of the byte size so any zero high-bits from ASCII text tend to collect which increases the chance of accidental collision.  It avoids multiplication so it may consume less power than something like Java's builtin String hashCode.

Comment: What is the hash going to be used for on the phone? Why can't you use standard hashing?

Comment: Besides collision issues (8 consecutive 0 blocks will yield exactly the same hash as nothing at all as one trivial example), the one-way property looks weak.  It starts with a base hash value.  Then for each integer in the pre-image, it bit-rotates exactly 1/2 an octet left and XORs the running hash value with the "current" integer in the pre-image.  Lastly it zeros the leftmost bit.  Some tricks aside, what you have is n/2 blocks of plain text XORd with n/2 other blocks of plain text offset 4 bits.  The Caesar cipher of hash functions.  In fairness I could not break it, but I bet pros could.

Comment: @WDS I guess if you feed it 8 bytes over and over again you would get alternating hash values (i.e. H(X) = H(X + 2 * N * X) ). Is that broken enough for you?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes More than broken enough. I actually was thinking about this more last night. When I said I could not break it, mainly I meant I could probably not get a good ASCII pre-image from the hash (assuming such a pre-image was used). But I could break it in other ways. There is no avalanche effect. A bit in the pre-image here will affect max 8 hash bits. Worse, given a pre-image and its hash, I can easily, if allowed to append just a single uint to the pre-image, output any hash I want. Calculate XOR of existing hash vs desired hash, allowing for bit rotation, and viola!

Comment: I came back to clarify and correct the comment I made an hour or so ago.  I had said a bit in the pre-image will affect at most 8 bits in the hash.  That is not correct.  It will affect one and only one bit in the hash.  That bit can be in one of 8 positions.  But anyway, because there is no avalanche effect, it is trivial to use a "throwaway" uint block as a mask to generate any hash output the attacker wishes.

Comment: If you want a good hash function, stick to SHA-2 or SHA-3. There are literally hundreds of proven implementations. Reinventing the wheel in cryptography can be extremely dangerous, even if you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't.

If you're trying to prevent tampering, a 31-bit hash is much too short, even ignoring any shortcomings of a specific function.  If you're trying to catch data corruption, a standard hash such as CRC-32 is almost as fast and is designed for the purpose.